# Using fastlane, how can I route one set of localized screenshots to two different app stores

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane

For example, my app supports French and I would like to use my French screenshots in both the French (**fr-FR**) app store, but also in the French Canadian (**fr-CA**) app store as well.

In the interest of time, I'd like to only run one of these during my screenshot creation phase, so I only have **fr-FR** under my languages option in my snapfile.

Therefor, is it possible to route the screenshots under **fr-FR** to **fr-CA** as well within iTunes Connect when running fastlane?

Looking through the [upload_to_app_store](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/) documentation, I have not found anything that appears to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a shell file that runs a copy script to create a new folder and copy the contents from French into the fr-CA folder.